# Does the MSI X58M motherboard support Digital Audio output?

Tags: motherboard, digital-audio

Does anyone own a [MSI X58M](http://www.msi.com/index.php?func=proddesc&maincat_no=1&cat2_no=170&prod_no=1796) mainboard? Are there any digital audio connectors on the board? Is it possible to send the audio digitally to my speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible, you need an SPDIF bracket, available from:

http://www.cclonline.com/product-info.asp?product_id=17746

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for in the product specifications is S/PDIF, which is the psudo-standard for sending digital audio to an amplifier.

Nowhere is S/PDIF mentioned on their website, nor can I find any reference to S/PDIF on any reputable websites, so I'm going to guess no.

Usually S/PDIF is provided by a breakout cable from the mobo on these kinds of boards, and finding someone who sells the breakout cable is often an exercise in futility as well...